# VBA - Use Directory Path on Server without Drive Letter

Tags: vba, excel

I have many macros that have the following path definition:

```
"X:\Test\3rd Party\Other Files\"
```

But what I need to, which is what I did with the vbscripts, is make it like this:

```
"\\ServerName\Folder\Test\3rd Party\Other Files\"
```

This is because the files that have the macros in them are on the server and they need to be able to be executed by anyone who has access to the server - and since each person might map the drive with a different letter and/or have different levels of access, the first option wont work.

When I use this:

```
"\\ServerName\Folder\Test\3rd Party\Other Files\"
```

I get the error:

> Sorry, we couldn't find \ServerName\Folder\Test\3rd Party\Other
>   Files. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

When I use this:

```
"\\ServerName\Folder\Test\3rd Party\Other Files"
```

- Note the backslash missing at the end of the string

I get the error:

> Excel cannot access "Other Files". The document may be read-only or
>   encrypted.

```
Sub RenameOriginalFilesSheets()

    Const TestMode = True
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rootpath = "\\ServerName\Folder\Test\Terminations\"

    aFile = Dir(rootpath & "*.xlsx")
    Do
        Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(rootpath & aFile, False, AddToMRU:=False)

        WB.Sheets(1).Name = Left$(WB.Name, InStrRev(WB.Name, ".") - 1)
        WB.Close True

        aFile = Dir()
        DoEvents
    Loop Until aFile = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please give an example of your code where this fails. See [mcve].

Comment: This could be because DNS is not recognising your server name. But as @Pᴇʜ said, you will have to provide your code for us to be able to help you

Comment: Enter your UNC-path in an explorer window - this will show you if the path is valid.

Comment: Thank you for the reply everyone. I have added an example of code I currently use and am trying to implement the change with.

Comment: @EitelDagnin What happens if you enter your `rootpath` like `\\ServerName\Folder\Test\Terminations\ ` in the address bar of the Explorer window in Windows? Does windows find it? Because I cannot reproduce it, it works for me.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it takes me to the correct location. Just checked

Comment: And which of these errors you get and in which line?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ its this line 'Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(rootpath & aFile, False, AddToMRU:=False)'

Comment: Ahhh, your code fails if there is no `xlsx` file in that folder. Change top of the loop to `Do While aFile <> vbNullString` and bottom to `Loop` only.

Comment: Ahhh! Damn, sometimes I wonder about myself lol.. One of the steps I have to converting the csv to xlsx and i didnt do that yet. I just tried to get the code working. Thank you very much @Pᴇʜ :)

Comment: @EitelDagnin It's always that, what you don't think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I test in VBA and it works.

```
Sub serverfolder()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("\\ServerIP\Folder\" & "*")
    Do While StrFile <> ""
         StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Aaron. Please see my post above, I have updated it as per comment requests with some sample code - which is virtually identical to yours. I think the only difference is that you use "ServerIP". Should I get the physical IP and use that instead of the name?